# How to wait for a batch file processing to end which is executed using Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder.start, before moving to the next statement?

Tags: java, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I have written a small application for a project..that will do following tasks:

1. Writes a commands.bat file. This bat file has some source-code-server commands that will take sometime to get process.
2. Executes the commands.bat using ProcessBuilder and get outputfile.txt using redirectOutput(File file) method.
3. Reads the outputfile.txt and get the desired output.

When I run this application, the program control starts with step-1 and executes it completely. In step-2 the control starts a process that drives the batch file. Now commands.bat file takes some time to finish (depends on the response from source code server). Sometimes this batch takes a little more than the reasonable time, for which the control is not waiting and starts executing step-3, and this way I am not getting the complete stream in the outfile.txt. 
I also used things like:

- waitfor(): Even with this control is not waiting for process to end(technically I may be wrong)
- Thread.sleep(). This is not working as time taken in batch file processing is not certain.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am waiting for a batch file to execute. Hopefully you have solved the problem by now. But, it might help someone else who looks at this question

`// Any command you want to run in my case im executing a batch file` 
`String cmd = "load_execute.bat";` 
`//FILE_PATH is the directory where to starting from`

```
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", cmd).redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.directory(new File(FILE_PATH));
        Process process = builder.start();

        //Redirect stream from cmd stream to local print stream
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();
        res = process.waitFor();`
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had tried this approach too, but with this approach, the control prints only some of the lines from the stream and then it hangs forever. It never comes out of that while loop. Also, this whole thing is not a standalone application, but it is getting executed from an Eclipse plugin. Still don't know why is it failing :(